# How Netty event loop maps to JVM thread resources?

Tags: java, jvm, netty, spring-webflux

I have WebFlux application and docker image of this application.
Running it via docker with CPU limits:

```
$ docker run -d --name my_webflux_app --cpus="1" -p 8080:8080 sample_webflux_image
```

Also, I have logs with CPU count while application startup

```
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        log.info("CPU: {}", Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    }
```

And I see next logs:

```
--- [main] CPU: 1
```

my_webflux_app - simple CRUD application. And what I noticed, while executing some basic operations, logs appended on different netty workers, like this:

```
--- [reactor-http-epoll-1] ...
--- [reactor-http-epoll-2] ...
--- [reactor-http-epoll-3] ...
--- [reactor-http-epoll-4] ...
```

For me, it seems clean, because Netty has a default value for workers - 4. So, how Netty workers map to existing CPU resources? And in what correlation? And how many types of Netty workers exist (epoll and e.t.c)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on how the user of netty constructs the `EventLoopGroup`(s). By default netty uses 2 * cores per `EventLoopGroup`.

Comment: Hello @Norman, thanks for this answer. Upvoted as well. However, I still do not understand, sorry. I am using default netty as well, as you suggested, I should see 2* cores per EventLoopGroup, but me to, on a 1CPU only machine, I am seeing reactor-http-epoll-1 to 4